# Special thanks to Members

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I wanted to personally thank all the SE members for helping me throughout the year, and appreciate all the SE members who are helping other users looking for help.

I am happy to see the way few members have been patient and polite with some of the questions/users . I saw some posts where people were expecting magic to happen, not understanding the fact this group is committed to help and not a consulting shop who gets paid for every right answer :(.

When I was looking at some questions and the comments, I personally felt some users were harsh/posting very minimal details of the problem yet wanted a quick solution. Irrespective of people's attitude help being offered to them makes this forum a special SE profile :)

Nothing personal but wanted to thank one and all :).

Thanks again to one and all and happy to a part of this forum \m/

Comment: This site is amazing .I have been very punctual in answering questions that i know and been learning by daily going through the answers and experimenting.Thanks everyone

Comment: Thnks StackExchange and some quick repliers.Thanks a lot